# Why won't my mySQL table data echo?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to print data from multiple tables onto one html table but I can't seem to figure out why nothing but the table headings are showing up.

```
<?php

include('includes/db_connect.php');

$query_student="SELECT student.firstName, student.lastName, major.major, major.gradDate, 
                FROM student
                JOIN major
                ON student.studentID=major.studentID";
    $result_student=mysqli_query($conn, $query_student);

echo '<table>
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th> 
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Graduate Year</th>
        <th>Major</th>
        <th>Activity After Graduation</th>
    </tr>';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_student))
{
    echo'<tr>'; // printing table row
        echo '<td>' . $row['firstName'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['lastName'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['gradDate'] . '</td>'; 
        echo '<td>' . $row['major'] . '</td>';
    echo'</tr>'; // closing table row
}
echo '</table>';

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Did you run the query in another enviroment, like phpMyAdmin, to see if it returns results?

Comment: Add error check after running a query

Answer (score 0):

Start by removing the `,` from your query, after `major.gradDate,` as you have no additional fields to follow.

You should really be checking for errors in your query to know what's happening...

Change: `$result_student=mysqli_query($conn, $query_student);`

To:

`$result_student=mysqli_query($conn, $query_student) or die( mysqli_error($conn) );`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the foreach statement and the `mysqli` object's `query` method.

I have also fixed your SQL, you need to `LEFT JOIN` when adding two tables together. Please first check this SQL statement works inside an environment since it is not yet tested.

```
$query_student="SELECT t1.firstName, t1.lastName, t2.major, t2.gradDate
                FROM student t1
                LEFT JOIN SECOND_TABLE t2
                ON t1.studentID = t2.studentID";

// Replace SECOND_TABLE with your table name you're joining on

?> <tr>
<?php
    if($conn): 
        foreach ($conn->query($query_student) as $row): ?>
        <!-- conditional statements allow HTML inside PHP loops -->
        <td> <?php echo $row['firstName']; ?> </td>
        // [...]
     <?php endforeach;
    else:
        die('Connection Error: ' . $conn->error);
    endif; ?>
</tr>
```

Hope this helped.